# How to add "dlew/joda-time-android" library to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, jodatime

I'm using joda time (version 2.8.2) library in my project and everything works fine, but I'd like to use the specialized version for Android, as explained here: [dlew/joda-time-android](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android)

While it was easy to add the joda time jar to Android Studio and adding the dependencies to the project, I didn't understand what to do in this case.
What do I have to download, where to put it and how to configure it.

Is there someone who did it and can write a step by step guide?
Thanks

Message update: I don't know why the question got two downvotes. I researched on Internet before posting the question. I also tried to contact the developer who posted the library on github. I didn't find an answer and it doesn't seem to be a stupid question, because I'm not getting tons of answers. I know I'm not an expert and for this reason I'm askingfor help, but before doing this, I always try to find a solution by myself. Thanks

Comment: At the moment I added the joda time jar in a custom directory called libs under the app directory of the project.
The I added the dependencies
dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the build.gradle file of your app:

```
dependencies  
{    
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4' 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio Choose File>Project Structure. Then click dependencies tab in project structure. Click the + symbol (upper right corner) and choose library depencendy and type net.danlew in search bar. Click on net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.9 (current version as of today) if not already highlighted and then choose OK.